# Property of a map on the 2D lattice

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, discrete-dynamical-systems

My brother ($A_1$) and I ($A_2$) are playing together with the following "game".

My brother picks a positive integer $m_1$ and then draw a line of length $m_1$ (units). I pick independently a positive integer $m_2$ and draw a line of length $m_2$. If the two lines are of the same length, i.e., $m_1=m_2$, then the game is over. If not, say, $m_1<m_2$, then $A_2$ draw a new line of length $m_2-m_1$ and denote this new length again as $m_2$; similarly, $A_1$ draws a new line of length $2m_1$ and denote the new length as $m_1$. If the new $m_1$ is equal to the new $m_2$, then the game is over, otherwise, we update $\min(m_1,m_2)$ by doubling it and update $\max(m_1,m_2)$ by stracting $\min(m_1,m_2)$ from it.

My question is: when exactly will this game be over?

The answer obviously depends on the initial integers we pick. I am wondering how.

One can describe the game with a map $f:X\to X$ where $X=\mathbb{Z}_+\times\mathbb{Z}_+$ and $\mathbb{Z}_+$ denotes the set of positive integers and
$$
f(x,y) := 
\begin{cases}
(2x,y-x)& \text{if $x<y$}\\
(x-y,2y)& \text{if $x>y$}\\
(x,y)   & \text{if $x=y$}\;.
\end{cases}
$$

Now the problem becomes the following

> For which $(x,y)\in X$ does there exist a positive integer $n$ such that
> $$
> f^{n}(x,y) = (c,c)
> $$
> for some integer $c$?

Here are some trivial observations:

- the sum of the two components of $f^{n}(x,y)$ is fixed for all $n$ as $M:=x+y$.
- if such $n$ and $c$ exists, i.e., the game is over, then we must have $2c = M$. In other words, $M=x+y$ must be even.
- Since the sum is fixed, by the pigeon hole principle, we must have
  $$
  f^{M}(x,y) \in S, S = \{f^{k}(x,y)\mid k = 1,2,\cdots, M-1\}\;.
  $$
  Therefore, the game will either stop, or repeat infinitely many times.

**QUESTION:** can one find an "iff" condition on $(x,y)$ so that the game will stop?

---

Suppose $x<y$. By looking at the sequence $\{2^kx:k=1,2,\cdots\}$, we can find the biggest $k$ such that
$$
2^{k}x<M-2^{k}x
$$
and
$$
2^{k+1}x\ge M-2^{k+1}x\tag{1}
$$
Thus, if we have
$$
2^{k+1}x= M-2^{k+1}x,
$$
i.e.,
$$
\frac{x+y}{x} = 2^{k+2}\tag{2}
$$
then the game will stop.

But one can soon find that this is not necessary by considering the orbit of $f$ on $(3,13)$:
$$
(3,13), (6,10), (12,4),(8,8)\;.
$$
Note that $(3+13)/3$ is not even an integer.

It is not difficult to find another sufficient (but not necessary) condition for stopping by assuming the strict inequality in (1) and doing the analysis again. But I don't now how to go on.

I made a conjecture that $x+y$ must be a power of $2$. But this can be quickly denied by the example of $(x,y) = (3,9)$.

Comment: Note that your function $f$ is homogenous, in the sense that for any $c\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$, $f(cx, cy) = f(x,y)$.
So you can reduce to the case of studying coprime $x, y$.
We can quickly discard the case where either of $x, y$ are even --- as you noticed $x + y$ must be even, and as $(x, y)$ are coprime they both cannot be.
So $(x, y)$ (after dividing by their GCD) must be coprime, and moreover must both be odd.

If both are odd, then $f(x, y)$ has both factors even, so we can reduce to the problem instance $\frac{1}{2}f(x, y)$, which has strictly smaller invariant $M = x + y$.

Comment: @Mark: Thank you for your comment. But I don't understand why $f$ is homogenous. Could you elaborate? I guess you meant to say something else like defining $f:X\to\{0,1\}$ where $1$ represents infinite loop and $0$ means stopping at some iteration?

Comment: What I mean is that, assuming $x\neq y$, \begin{align*}f(cx, cy) &= (2\min(cx, cy), \max(cx, cy) - \min(cx, cy))\\&= (2c\min(x, y), c\max(x, y) - c\min(x, y)) \\&= c(2\min(x, y), \max(x, y) - \min(x, y)) \\&= cf(x, y)\end{align*}. If $x = y$ then $cx = cy$ and $f(cx, cy) = cx = cf(x, y)$. So in all cases, if $c\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$, $f(cx, cy) = cf(x, y)$.

Comment: (I think perhaps the confusion was because @Mark's [initial](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368327/property-of-a-map-on-the-2d-lattice#comment929295_368327) comment inadvertently omitted the third factor of $c$ in $f(c x, c y) = c f(x, y)$.)

Comment: @Mark: Thanks a lot for the details! I was confused by the typo $f(cx,cy)=f(x,y)$ in your first comment, which should be $f(cx,cy)=cf(x,y)$. It is now clear. I have changed the definition of $f$ slightly, which does not affect the essence of its property; and it is still homogeneous.

Comment: @LSpice: yes indeed. I was writing my comment when you posted yours. :)

Comment: @Mark: I see how homogeneity of $f$ implies that we can assume that $\gcd(x,y)=1$ and both $x$ and $y$ are odd. What do you mean in the first comment by "If both are odd, then (,) has both factors even"?

Comment: @kuma WLOG assume that both $x, y$ are odd and $x < y$. Then $f(x, y) = (2x, y-x)$. $2x$ is clearly even, but $y - x$ is as well (as $y-x\bmod 2 = 1 - 1\bmod 2 = 0$). So you can apply homogeneity to examine $\frac{1}{2}f(x, y) = (x, \frac{y-x}{2})$. If these are both odd again ($x$ already clearly is) you can repeat the process indefinitely. In this particular case you get that provided $x\equiv y\equiv 1\bmod 2$ and $x\not\equiv y\bmod 4$ you can repeat the process twice. I have not thought about the conditions for repeating it higher numbers of times.